# I am trying to edit an arduino library. Could someone explain this piece of code for me please

Tags: shared-libraries, arduino-c++

```
#if defined(__AVR__)

#define pew                                                                    \
  asm volatile("ld  __tmp_reg__, %a[ptr]+"                                     \
               "\n\t"                                                          \
               "out %[data]    , __tmp_reg__"                                  \
               "\n\t"                                                          \
               "out %[clk]     , %[tick]"                                      \
               "\n\t"                                                          \
               "out %[clk]     , %[tock]"                                      \
               "\n" ::[ptr] "e"(ptr),                                          \
               [ data ] "I"(_SFR_IO_ADDR(DATAPORT)),                           \
               [ clk ] "I"(_SFR_IO_ADDR(CLKPORT)), [ tick ] "r"(tick),         \
               [ tock ] "r"(tock));
#endif

    // Loop is unrolled for speed:
    pew pew pew pew pew pew pew pew pew pew pew pew pew pew pew pew pew pew pew
        pew pew pew pew pew pew pew pew pew pew pew pew pew
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the `pew`, this is called loop unrolling.

> Loop unrolling, also known as loop unwinding, is a loop transformation
> technique that attempts to optimize a program's execution speed at the
> expense of its binary size, which is an approach known as space–time
> tradeoff. The transformation can be undertaken manually by the
> programmer or by an optimizing compiler. On modern processors, loop
> unrolling is often counterproductive, as the increased code size can
> cause more cache misses; cf. Duff's device.[1]
>
> The goal of loop unwinding is to increase a program's speed by
> reducing or eliminating instructions that control the loop, such as
> pointer arithmetic and "end of loop" tests on each iteration;[2]
> reducing branch penalties; as well as hiding latencies, including the
> delay in reading data from memory.[3] To eliminate this computational
> overhead, loops can be re-written as a repeated sequence of similar
> independent statements.[4]

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling